# Interromper a execução de uma função JavaScript para executar outra função

Tags: javascript, angularjs

estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando angular e tenho a seguinte função:

```
    function drawLatLong(i, arrayIdColetor) { 
.....
         (não exibi o código por ser grande e achar desnecessário que vcs o analisem)
.....
      });
```

Essa função é invocada em um for:

```
for(var j = 0; j < $kinvey.arrayIdColetor.length;  j++){
   drawLatLong(j, $kinvey.arrayIdColetor);          
 }
```

A função *drawLatLong* que é invocada N vezes conforme o FOR, demora um tempo considerável para ser executada, pois ela faz pesquisas relativamente pesadas na base de dados.

O problema que estou tendo é que se o usuário invocar outra função sem que a função *drawLatLong* tenha finalizado, o sistema não se comporta como deve.

Teria alguma forma de manter essa situação sob controle? Ou seja, só permitir que o usuário execute outra função depois que a *drawLatLong* tenha sido finalizada?
Ou seria possível interromper a execução da função *drawLatLong* no meio, caso outra função seja invocada pelo usuário?

Espero ter sido claro.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você foi claro sim. Eu nunca pensei em chamar uma função de chamada para o banco em um laço. Podemos iniciar o solução tirando essa chamada de dentro do laço. Imagina se dá pau nesse laço e ele fica infinito.... crash no seu database.

Comment: uma simples condição "if" não resolveria o seu problema?

Comment: @durtto preciso fazer essa chamada dentro do laço porque eu busco a latitude e longitude de acordo com o idColetor (1 idColetor identifica 1 veiculo), então se eu tiver 3 idColetors (ou 3 veiculos) eu preciso pegar as coordenadas de cada um dos veiculos e imprimir na tela, não sei se fui claro. Abs.

Comment: @IvanFerrer utilizando um if como eu poderia interromper a execução de uma função no meio para executar outra que foi invocada pelo usuário? Obg

Comment: A ideia não é interroper o script, mas sair dele...

Comment: Para interromper vc pode usar `try { ...} catch(err) { ... } finally { ... }`.

Comment: Outra coisa que você pode fazer é dar um `break;` no seu laço `for`, se uma condição ou outra função seja invocada.

Comment: @S_A, pensou em executar o `drawLatLong` em um WebWorker? ao fazer isto, você não irá ocupar a sua thread principal.

Comment: @TobyMosque segue o q quero fazer: ao abrir a tela eu busco no banco a latitude e longitude de vários veículos (para tal utilizo o `for(var j = 0; j < $kinvey.arrayIdColetor.length;  j++){ ... }`. A função `drawLatLong` é responsável por exibir essas coordenadas na tela, sendo que cada veiculo terá o seu traçado. O problema é que enquanto isso é feito, pode ser que o usuário selecione para ver o traçado de apenas 1 veiculo, dessa forma, a função de exibir apenas um traçado é executado em paralelo com a função `drawLatLong` que ainda está em execução. Acho q o WebWorker n ajudaria. O q acha?Obg

Comment: olha, isto vai depender da implementação, ao carregar a pagina você pode usar um `WebWorker` por veiculo e carregar a `longitude` e a `latitude` em paralelo e só liberar a pagina quando todos os `WebWorker` enviarem a mensagem de retorno... desta forma o metódo para exibir apenas um traçado não vai precisar refazer a consultar, apenas aplicar um filtro na pagina... mas como disse, tudo depende da sua implementação.

Comment: Provavelmente dará certo @TobyMosque, mas antes vou tentar alguma alternativa que me exija menos alterações no código. Obg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um callback para que o proximo `"for"` só seja executado no final da `drawLatLong`.

```
function drawLatLong(i, arrayIdColetor, callback) { 
    .....
    (não exibi o código por ser grande e achar desnecessário que vcs o analisem)
    .....
    callback(); 
};
```

No lugar do `for` você pode usar uma função na qual será "chamada" (executada) assim que o drawLatlong finalizar.

```
function callFor(j, arrayIdColetor) {
  if (j < arrayIdColetor.length)
    drawLatLong(j, arrayIdColetor, function() {
      callFor(j + 1, arrayIdColetor)
    });
}
callFor(0, $kinvey.arrayIdColetor);
```

Segue uma demostração (com alteração proposta no comentário):

```js
    var $kinvey = {
      arrayIdColetor: [5, 12, 124, 636, 47, 45]
    }

    function addEl(txt) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = txt;
      document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(li);
    }

    function add400(callback) {
      addEl(400);
      callback();
    }

    function drawLatLong(i, arrayIdColetor, callback) {
      addEl(arrayIdColetor[i]);
      setTimeout(function() { //faz uma execução assíncrona
        add400(function() {
          setTimeout(function() { //faz outra execução assíncrona
            //esse callback() foi passado como parâmetro da função "drawLatLong"
            callback();
          }, 1000);
        });
      }, 1000);
    };

    function callFor(j, arrayIdColetor) {
      if (j < arrayIdColetor.length)
        drawLatLong(j, arrayIdColetor, function() {
          callFor(j + 1, arrayIdColetor)
        });
    }
    callFor(0, $kinvey.arrayIdColetor);
```

```html
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Comment: suponha que enquanto estiver printando na tela os números 5, 12, 124... o usuário invoque uma função que faz imprimir o número 400, por ex. Como eu poderia fazer para interromper o print dos números 5,12,124,636,47 e 45 para que imprimisse apenas o número 400? Se isso for possível conseguirei resolver meu problema. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Se conseguiu uma reposta, marque como aceita. Obrigado

Comment: assim que conseguir marcarei @durtto

Comment: essa função que imprimi 400 precisa seguir a mesma metodologia de uma função assíncrona, sendo assim, o callback "chamaria" (executaria) o callback da anterior que foi passado como função. Vou alterar a questão para te dar um exemplo.

Comment: @LeandroAmorim e se eu quiser que a função add400 seja executada somente depois que todo o callFor seja executado? Obrigado

Comment: @LeandroAmorim a pg não está disponível.

Comment: @S_A https://jsfiddle.net/LAmorim/L3v5xcw1/

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso você vai precisar usar [.promisse()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).
Com ele você poderá fazer programação assíncrona com javascript.

[Veja esse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/deshpandeakhil/NrXGW/light/)

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "p" ).append( "Started..." );

  $( "div" ).each(function( i ) {
    $( this ).fadeIn().fadeOut( 1000 * ( i + 1 ) );
  });

  $( "div" ).promise().done(function() {
    $( "p" ).append( " Finished! " );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma simples condição IF não resolveria o problema?

```
var executandoAcao = function () {
 for (var j = 0; j < $kinvey.arrayIdColetor.length;  j++) {
   drawLatLong(j, $kinvey.arrayIdColetor);          
 }
return true;
}();

if (executandoAcao) {
      outrafuncao();
}
```

Se pretende interromper no meio do laço, fazendo assim também funciona:

```
 function executandoAcao(interromper) {

     for (var j = 0; j < $kinvey.arrayIdColetor.length;  j++) {
             drawLatLong(j, $kinvey.arrayIdColetor);
          if (interromper) {
             break;
          }          
     }
    return true;
 }

 var interromper = (outraFuncao) ? true : false;
 executandoAcao(interromper);

 var outraFuncao = function() {
     var promise = false;
     //aqui a outra função que vc quer executar
     $('#elemento').on('click', function() {
         promise = true;
     });
 return promise;
 }();
```

Comment: realmente funciona, mas continuo com o seguinte problema: suponha que esse for invocará a função `drawLatLong` 3x, ao interromper a execução pode ser que eu já tenha executado o `drawLatLong 2x`, certo? Ou seja, além de interromper conforme vc sugeriu, tbm terei que fazer com que a função invocada pelo usuário seja executada somente após sair do for. Não sei se fui claro. Obg